# What are the current productions of the Star Trek Universe and are they planning to make more?

Tags: star-trek

The Star Trek universe is a pretty large universe with its end hardly in sight. I know one should stay away from a list when asking questions, but many Star Trek-ies want to know what I'm asking. I want to know: What are all the current productions (film work, ie... Series, Movies, Short Films, etc.)? And are there plans for another production? Such as one containing more time travel?

My Current Knowledge is, Star Trek (orginal), Star Trek 2-7, Star Trek Original Series, Star Trek TNG, Star Trek DS9, Star Trek Voyager, Star Trek The Animates Series, Star Trek Enterprise, and the new Star Trek movie. Let me know what I missed, please.

Comment: We try to be time insensitive here. Can you think of any way to edit your question to remove the dependency on a time-frame?

Comment: Ok, corrected... I don't quite understand why because time plays a vital part in Sci-Fi, as in life, but... I'm happy to help.

Comment: The intention of the Q&A is to provide concrete and eternal answers to questions. If the question depends on a time like 'current' then the target moves with time. So this question will become useless in 2 years. We try to avoid that. :)

Comment: Oh... Drat, I'll keep that in mind when I ask further questions. Unfortunately my question relates to the production path of Star Trek so it is time sensitive. When I ask other questions, I'll be sure to ask time insensitive ones.

Comment: VTC as Too Localized:  The question has been around for a year and a half, and the answer has [tentatively changed](http://trekmovie.com/2012/11/13/abrams-not-interested-in-directing-star-wars-vii-planning-new-original-project/) ("I have some original stuff I am working on next.”)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently CBS is just planning on continuing the new movie franchise.  They're working on a sequel to the J.J. Abrams movie from 2009.  That's all they're planning for TV/movies.

There are many Star Trek books that have been, and continue to be, published as well.

I don't believe there are any plans for more Star Trek animated TV shows or movies.

Side note: your question says you're familiar with the films 1-7.  They made 8-10 prior to the recent movie.  They're titled *Star Trek: First Contact, Star Trek: Insurrection*, and *Star Trek: Nemesis.*  First Contact is especially fun, if you're a fan of TNG.

Comment: Thank you for reminding to list them. Sadly, nothing that I haven't seen yet. :(

Comment: @Justin: IMHO, "First Contact" was great, "Insurrection" was bearable, and "Nemesis" was terrible.

Comment: @Dima Yeah, thus maintaining the "Even movies are good, odd movies are bad, and divisible by 5 are terrible" rule of Star Trek movies.

Comment: I thought Insurrection was the worst of the 3 they did. Felt more like a really long TNG episode. I liked Nemesis, Tom Hardy always plays a great villain.

Comment: Yes it did, but it had cool additions. It's what a good episode would have looked like if they had a bigger budget... I suppose.