# What plans were there for Star Trek: DS9 or Voyager movies?

Tags: star-trek, movie, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, behind-the-scenes

Obviously there were never any such movies made, and never will be. But I'm interested in how far any planning ever went.

What were the firmest any plans to produce a movie featuring DS9 or Voyager got?

Comment: I find your lack of faith disturbing. Also please provide your e-mail address so that I can send you my Morn-centric DS9 screenplay.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:  I was hoping for a Broadway musical.

Comment: Related: [Are there any plans for a new Star Trek TV series?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/96/35), also [What are the current productions of the Star Trek Universe and are they planning to make more?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2958/35)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I believe Morn deserves his own spin-off series: _That's My Morn!_ or maybe _Top of the Morn to You_

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: I’m envisaging *Top of the Morn to You* as a harrowing account of one man/creature’s descent into alcoholism against a backdrop of interstellar war.

Comment: There is something of a movement for a Captain Worf series.

Comment: Howdy @ThePopMachine.  It's been a long time since this question.  Anything else you're lookin' for? :-
)

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Glad to be of help, and thanks. :-)

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Actually, I also took the opportunity to update the answer with a relevant quote from this past summer's convention.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## No plans for *DS9* or *Voyager* films were ever revealed publicly

There is no evidence that any of the major creative staff behind the *TNG-DS9-Voyager* era — Rick Berman, Brannon Braga, Michael Piller, Jeri Taylor, etc. — had ever planned films for either *DS9* or *Voyager*.  If there were plans, even very preliminary ones, they were never commented on publicly.

Of course, there must have been at least some discussion amongst the creative staff.  Here are my speculations about how these discussions would have played out:

- By the time *DS9* and *Voyager* were wrapping up, the *TNG* film series was still in progress.  The producers probably felt that more juice could be squeezed from those characters who, on the whole, had a larger, more loyal fan base than the *DS9* or *Voyager* characters.
- The *TNG* films, like the *Original Series* films before them, have only a mild back-story burden, given the highly episodic nature of the shows that spawned them.  It was possible to make a film like *Insurrection* which one could watch knowing only little about *Star Trek*, which makes the concept easy to pitch to the studio (which is interested in maximizing returns).  Even *First Contact*, the most successful *TNG* film, was able to re-introduce the Borg without alienating newer fans.
- In contrast, *DS9* and *Voyager* were not very user-friendly when it came to attracting a newer audience.  The Dominion saga would have carried a massive back-story burden for the average cinema-goer.  With some creativity, there is a possibility that *Voyager* could have been adapted into a general-audience film, but while *Voyager* played well on the television, I suspect it would have lacked the necessary "umph" for the silver screen.
- The failure of *Nemesis* in 2003 and the lack of solid ratings numbers for *Enterprise* basically killed the Prime Timeline of *Star Trek* as we know it.  Making *DS9* or *Voyager* films was not going to fix this.

All in all, both *DS9* and *Voyager* would have been better suited to a **television movie** or a **further mini-series** than to the full cinematic treatment.

But then hold on...

## *Voyager* did have a “movie” (on television)

*Voyager* actually had a television movie, titled *[Voyager: Dark Frontier](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Frontier_(episode))*. It was a feature-length, made-for-tv movie.  It aired during Season 5, but was advertised officially by the UPN Network as a movie:

> **VOICE-OVER:** *The Voyager movie you thought you'd never see...Voyager: Dark Frontier, a Star Trek movie event.*

Because the film now airs in syndication as a two-part episode, many have forgotten that this was a genuine made-for-tv movie.

## Plans for Seven of Nine in *Nemesis*

While there wasn't a plan for a full-blown *Voyager* film in cinemas, there was an intention to include certain *Voyager* characters in *Nemesis*.  Apart from Admiral Janeway's cameo, there were plans to have **Jeri Ryan star in *Nemesis*, with Seven of Nine as an Enterprise-E crew member.**

However, the actress turned down the role:

- [Jeri Ryan explains why she turned down *Star Trek: Nemesis* role](http://trekmovie.com/2011/06/08/jeri-ryan-explains-why-she-turned-down-in-star-trek-nemesis-role/)

**UPDATE (Aug 2017):** This week, at the Las Vegas Star Trek convention, Marina Sirtis revealed the following about the Jeri Ryan in *Nemesis* issue:

> "When I was negotiating for *Nemesis* they literally threatened to fire me and recast Troi, well not actually recast, but they said **"We are going to fire you and hire Jeri Ryan (Seven of Nine from *Star Trek Voyager*)."** And I said "Well Jeri Ryan won’t do it for that money, that is for sure."

([Source](http://trekmovie.com/2017/08/05/stlv17-marina-sirtis-says-paramount-threatened-to-replace-her-with-jeri-ryan-for-star-trek-nemesis/))

## Further Reading

There is some interesting discussion on the issue of making a *DS9* film here:

- [TrekBBS — Why wasn't there ever a *DS9* movie?](http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?t=94781)

Also, actor Garrett Wang (Harry Kim) discussed his pitch for a *Voyager* film, and how it was ignored, in this interview:

- [Garrett Wang talks clashes with Brannon Braga & Rick Berman + lost opportunity for *Star Trek: Voyager* movie](http://trekmovie.com/2011/06/22/garrett-wang-talks-clashes-with-brannon-braga-rick-berman-lost-opportunity-for-star-trek-voyager-movie/)

## UPDATE (Aug 2016): *DS9* showrunner Behr explains lack of *DS9* movie in terms of show's goals

At the **Star Trek 50th Anniversary Celebration in Las Vegas**, Ira Steven Behr commented on the *DS9* movie issue, effectively saying that such a thing was never in their sights:

> **BEHR:** Even today, I still get the question: will there be a DS9 movie? ***I love the thought but even at the time, we knew that would never happen***....At the same time, that gave us the opportunity to not worry about where the show was going to go in another iteration….We were just going to go the distance and end it as best we could. I think that last image of Jake and Kira looking out the window, there's so much going on in that tableau: hope, sadness, questioning the future. It seemed like the perfect way to end the series. The station’s still there. It’s not going away. It’s not pulling away, we are. It's getting smaller, but it’s still there. It felt like a good way to go out.

([Source](https://thesffblog.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-5-getting-deep-into-ds9-star-trek-writers-reflect-on-the-tng-era-and-the-star-trek-rat-pack-steals-the-show/))

Comment: And with a whimper this whole "event" nonsense began

Comment: IMHO DS9 did not need a film.  They had a story they wanted to tell, they told it, the end.  The story reached an entirely satisfactory stopping point.  Trying to tack on a sequel would have ruined it.

Comment: @Kevin : The *DS9* showrunner, Ira Steven Behr, agrees with you (see [here](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-5-getting-deep-into-ds9-star-trek-writers-reflect-on-the-tng-era-and-the-star-trek-rat-pack-steals-the-show/)).  Actually, I'll add this into the answer, as it is relevant.

Comment: "Voyager played well on the television, I suspect it would have lacked the necessary "umph" for the silver screen."
At the end of the day, any ongoing TV storyline makes a movie untenable. Sure, you can makes long filler episodes, and call them movies, if you want, but they will never really be movies.

Comment: @Praxis, there are recent stories on Marina Sirtis commenting on Jeri Ryan in Nemesis,  if you'd  like to add more....

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Done. :-)

Comment: Makes me wonder what would have happened with Seven on the "steering wheel". Crashing the Enterprise into enemy vessels doesn't sound to be a very efficient strategy.

Comment: Data/Seven dialogue is an unrealised gem.